# remove duplicate in multi-dimensional array with only one value is duplicate in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

This is a multidimensional array. And only remove the duplicate value in name. or specific index or key.

```
$array = Array(
  Array(
    'name'  => 'duplicate',
    'slug'  => 'test'
  ),
  Array(
    'name'  => 'Foo',
    'slug'  => 'Bar'
  ),
  Array(
    'name'  => 'duplicate',
    'slug'  => 'Bar'
  ),
  Array(
    'name'  => 'test',
    'slug'  => 'Foo'
  ),
);
```

The expected output should be:

```
$array = Array(
  Array(
    'name'  => 'duplicate',
    'slug'  => 'test'
  ),
  Array(
    'name'  => 'Foo',
    'slug'  => 'Bar'
  ),
  Array(
    'name'  => 'test',
    'slug'  => 'Foo'
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do:

```
$temp = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $arr) {
  if(in_array($arr['name'], $temp)) continue;
  $temp[] = $arr['name'];
  $res[]  = $arr;
}    
print_r($res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$targetArray = [];

foreach( $array as $element ) {
  if( false == array_key_exists( $element['name'], $targetArray) ) {
    $targetArray[$element['name']] = $element;
  }
}
```

`$targetArray` will have the desired result but it will also have an extra key by the name of `'name'` attribute in `$array`. If you are ok with the extra key, this code is easier to read.